# CSS style equivalent of "object-fit: cover" for IE

Tags: html, css, media-queries, object-fit

I have a full width banner and Im using this style :

```css
.headline--hero {
  width: 100%;
  min-width: 100%;
  padding: 0;
  height: 490px;
}

@media (max-width: 1024px) {
  .headline--hero {
    height: 46vw;
  }
}

.headline--hero>h2 {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
}

.headline--hero>h2>img {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  object-fit: cover;
}
```

This works just fine with Chrome. When I zoome out using `CTRL+-` the full width banner adjust fine.
In IE however it broken looks like the style `object-fit: cover;` is not working. I tried using

```css
.headline--hero>h2 {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  left: 50%;
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
}

.headline--hero>h2>img {
  height: auto;
  width: 100%;
}
```

The width of the banner is working fine it gets all 100% but the height is the problem, my guess is since there is a position absolute the image is not moving height so the image is not getting the complete height.

> Is there a way to replicate the style `object-fit: cover;` in IE other the one I tried?

Comment: Have you tried `background-size: cover;`?

Comment: @BertW no i havent will look it up and give it a try

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately `object-fit` is not supported in IE

Here is the article I've found - https://css-tricks.com/almanac/properties/o/object-fit/

You can try `background-size: cover;` 
As a guy in comments mentioned before